# How to wait for the url to reload in angular 2 app

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am struggling with this in angular 2. I refresh the url and want to wait for a page to complete loading the url. Then I want to do sth. Unfortunately, I dont succeed:

```
getLoginScreen() {
  return this.http.get(myService.LOGIN_URL)
.flatMap(result => this.changeBrowserUrl())
.subscribe( result => //i want to do sth when the page is loaded//);
}

changeBrowserUrl(): Observable<any> {
return Observable.create( observer => {
window.location.href = myService.LOGIN_URL;
observer.next();
});
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by wait for the url? url or response? What is sth?

Comment: What's the problem with "i want to do sth when the page is loaded"?

Comment: I am on the 1st page (my default app page). Then I redirect to go to another url. I want to wait for that page to load. When it finishes loading, I want to get the parameter from that new url address.

Comment: In which context waiting means. You want to show spinner or something or you are talking about page life cycle hook?

Comment: Changing `window.location.href` triggers page reload. Angular 2 has to load itself again.
I'd recommend using a pure JavaScript for `domready` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

Comment: micronyks , I just want to wait (page life cycle hook)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in the way you are trying.  When you load a new URL, the current page is unloaded and the new page is loaded.

Your 2 options are:

A - just have some JavaScript in the new page which does its processing when it loads.

B - build a Single Page App

Comment: I have a single page app, but I must go to the other component through the login service they provide, to get the authentication token from them in order to have possibility to make requests for data to them.

Comment: then just add some code to your app's startup code to check the url for the login service parameters.  If they aren't there, then your app is running BEFORE the login.  If they are there, then it is running AFTER the login